# Converting string to emoji

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, emoji

I have the following function which replaces string codes with given emoji characters.

```
export const CHARS = {
  ":)": "",
  "(:": "",
  ":-)": "",
  ":(": "",
  "):": "",
  ":-(": "",
  ":/": "",
}

convertEmoji = string => {
    const escape = s => s.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&")
    const pattern = new RegExp(
      Object.keys(CHARS).map(escape).join("|"),
      "g"
    )
    return string.replace(pattern, match => CHARS[match])
}
```

This works as expected but it also converts when any of the given CHARS[key] is present in a word.

For example, passing this function to a string that contains a URL:

```
https://google.com
```

Becomes:

```
https/google.com
```

I want the replace function to be worked only when the emoji code is presented as words in a given sentence. For example:

**:) Hello world!** - Here the function should work.

**:)Hello world!** - Here it should not work as the emoji code does not have the correct spaces.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: _Why_ would you pass `https://google.com` to  `convertEmoji` in the first place?

Comment: You could add negative lookarounds to prevent matching if there are certain characters before or after it.

Comment: @h0r53 Presumably it's user chat input, and they might type a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the left- and right-hand side context for your pattern.

If you want to make sure there are no word chars immediately on the left and right, you need unambiguous word boundaries that are expressed with `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` lookarounds:

```js
new RegExp('(?<!\\w)(?:' + Object.keys(CHARS).map(escape).join("|") + ')(?!\\w)', "g")
```

Or, alternatively, you can rely on whitespace boundaries, that require whitespace char or start/end of string on both ends:

```js
new RegExp('(?<!\\S)(?:' + Object.keys(CHARS).map(escape).join("|") + ')(?!\\S)', "g")
```

Choose the solution based on your requirements and precise the patterns in the lookarounds if you need to further precise boundary patterns.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a space requirement, you could add that requirement to the `CHARS`.

```js
const CHARS = {
  ":) ": " ",
  "(:": "",
  ":-)": "",
  ":(": "",
  "):": "",
  ":-(": "",
  ":/": "",
}

convertEmoji = string => {
    const escape = s => s.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&")
    const pattern = new RegExp(
      Object.keys(CHARS).map(escape).join("|"),
      "g"
    )
    return string.replace(pattern, match => CHARS[match])
}

console.log(convertEmoji(":) Hello world!"))
console.log(convertEmoji(":)Hello world!"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not able to use any spaces in the object key as this function is triggered when the space bar is pressed. So having a space character in the object key would require 2 space bar presses to replace the code with emoji.